# How to read custom header in CORS middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I have created CORS middleware using [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package. This middleware will be called before each call. Here is my implementation.

```
const corsMiddleware = async (req, callback) => {
  const { userid } = req.headers|| req.cookies {};
  let whiteList = await getWhiteListDomains(userid)
  return callback(null, {
    origin: whiteList,
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: ["userid", "authorization", "content-type"]
  });
};
```

And added this middleware before route initialization as

```
app.use(cors(corsMiddleware));
app.options("*", cors(corsMiddleware));



app.get("/user", (req, res, next)=>{
    // code
})
```

From Browser I am trying to call the API as

```
axios({ method: "get", url: "http://localhost:3000/user", headers: {userId:"1234"} });
```

While debugging on the server I see

```
access-control-request-headers:"userid"
```

in the headers of the request object.

I am not able to read the custom header. This might be happening because I am trying to read the custom header before CORS initialization. But still, I want to read that custom header.

Comment: Exactly what request header are you trying to read?

Comment: @sideshowbarker I have passed userid in the header. Now I want to read that header in cors middleware.

Comment: The question as currently written is unclear and lacks details that would be necessary for anybody to answer it. You should update the question to include an explanation about hw you’re testing. Are you sending a request from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser? If so, what does that code look like? And have you checked the browser devtools console? What are the exact messages the browser is logging there?

Comment: @sideshowbarker I have updated the question. Please see this can help you to understand

Comment: What are the exact messages that the browser is logging in the devtools console?

Comment: @sideshowbarker As middleware does not found userId in header so not able to get whitelist domains. My CORS middleware code is returning  ````origin: undefined````, It is returning CORS issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mainly two problems in your code.

First one, and easier to solve is that you are missing `access-control-allow-origin` in the option that sets the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`:

```
return callback(null, {
  origin: whiteList,
  credentials: true,
  allowedHeaders: [
    "access-control-allow-origin",
    "authorization",
    "content-type",
    "userid"
  ]
});
```

The second one is the most important because it is related to how CORS works.
This problem you are having is that CORS is already rejecting the petition in the  pre-flight `OPTIONS` request. It never allows the browser to execute the `GET` request.

You say that you want to read the custom header `userId` in the pre-flight `OPTIONS` request but you can't. The reason is because the pre-flight `OPTIONS` request is created by the browser automatically and it won't use the custom headers you are setting up in the Axios call. It will only send [these headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) for the CORS:

```
Origin // URL that makes the request
Access-Control-Request-Method // Method of the request is going to be executed 
Access-Control-Request-Headers // Headers allowed in the request to be executed
```

Because your custom header is not being sent so in the pre-flight `OPTIONS` when you try to access the value of `userId`, you get an `undefined` value:

```
const { userid } = req.headers|| req.cookies;
console.log(userid); // undefined
```

And because you are using that value that is not matching in your async function `getWhiteListDomains` probably getting another `undefined`, the value set up in the `origin` option of the CORS middleware is `undefined` that provokes the CORS middleware rejects the pre-flight `OPTIONS` request.

```
let whiteList = await getWhiteListDomains(userid); // userid === undefined
console.log(whitelist); // undefined
return callback(null, {
  origin: whiteList, // undefined
  credentials: true,
  allowedHeaders: ["userid", "authorization", "content-type"]
});
```

I am not totally sure which is your goal trying to use your custom header as CORS check, but my advise would be when dealing with customised CORS configuration to only check the `Origin` header because that's its purpose: [to limit and control which URLs can access to your server and resources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

If you are interested in creating any kind of authorisation or limited by user implementation in the requests received by your server, I suggest you to use a different custom middleware and not involve CORS at all like you are trying now.

Answer (score 0):

you must parse your request

try this 
`npm i body-parser`

and

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```